# Hide date in listview if it is from the same date

Tags: android, date, listview, cursor, adapter

How do I hide the date in my ListView if the message is from the same day? I want to display the date once if the messages comes from the same day.

My code is as below:

```
        final message Message = getItem(cursor.getPosition());

        //Get next chat message
        message nextChatMessage;

        if (cursor.getPosition() > 0) {
            //Move cursor forward
            nextChatMessage = getItem(cursor.getPosition() + 1);
        } else {
            nextChatMessage = null;
        }

        boolean isDiffDate = (nextChatMessage == null || !DateTimeUtil.isEqualDate(message.messageDate, nextChatMessage.messageDate));
```

Get item:

```
    @Override
public Message getItem(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToPosition(getCount() - position - 1)) {
        message Message = new message ();
        Message .parseChatMessage(cursor);
        return Message ;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You would usually hide a view in `getView`, so that would be actually interesting code to add to your question.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg, Hi. I hide the view in getView if the Boolean value is True.

Comment: Well, the date is the same day, if `isDiffDate` is `false`, **not** `true`. However, it would also be interesting to know what `DateTimeUtil.isEqualDate` returns.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg, if the two dates are different it would return a true and it will show the two different dates. If the dates are the same, it will only show the date for the first time and hide the other messages with similiar date. But, my 'nextChatMessage' does not point to the next cursor. Thus, the dates compared with the current date mixes up the actual date. Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this perhaps what you wish to do in the `getView`?

```
myDateView.setVisibility(isDiffDate ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I've set the visibilty of the date in my getView() method. In my case, I wish that if the two dates are different it would return a true and it will show the two different dates. If the dates are the same, it will only show the date for the first time and hide the other messages with similiar date. But, my 'nextChatMessage' does not point to the next cursor. Thus, the dates compared with the current date mixes up the actual date. Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to set visibility of view if date is same or different
in getView() method of adapter

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I've set the visibilty of the date in my getView() method. In my case, I wish that if the two dates are different it would return a true and it will show the two different dates. If the dates are the same, it will only show the date for the first time and hide the other messages with similiar date. But, my 'nextChatMessage' does not point to the next cursor. Thus, the dates compared with the current date mixes up the actual date. Please advice. Thank you.